# Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denote the Gaussian integers. The set of units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ denote the Gaussian integers. The set of units of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is $\{\pm 1, \pm i\}.$

A proof from:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Units_of_Gaussian_Integers

(Proof 2)

Proof. Let $\alpha =a+bi$ be a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Then by definition of unit:

$ \exists \beta =c+di \in \mathbb{Z}[i]:\alpha \beta =1$
Let $|\alpha|$ denote the modulus of $\alpha.$

Then:

$|\alpha|^2 \cdot |\beta|^2 =|\alpha \beta|^2 = |1|^2=1$

$(\star) \hspace{1mm}$ Since  $|\alpha|$ and $|\beta|$ are positive integers $\Longrightarrow a^2+b^2=|\alpha \beta|^2=1$

$\textbf{The step above } (\star)$ doesn't make sense to me. We have that $|\alpha|^2 = a^2+b^2,$ but it says that $|\alpha \beta|^2 = a^2+b^2$ so that $|\alpha|^2 = |\alpha \beta|^2.$ Why does $|\alpha \beta|^2 = a^2 + b^2$ when $\alpha = a + bi$?

Comment: We have $1=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ so $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=1=|\alpha \beta|^2$.

Comment: The last step is a typo (even though the statement is true). Should be something more along the line.

$$|\alpha|^2|\beta|^2 =|\alpha\beta|^2 = 1 \implies |\alpha|^2 = |\beta|^2 = 1 \implies a^2 + b^2 = |\alpha|^2 = 1$$

Comment: Seems to be a typo. If you read $\lvert \alpha\rvert^2$ instead of  $\lvert \alpha\beta\rvert^2$, everything is coherent.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you.